# calling angular2 service with es5 not with es6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to call a method in angular2 service using es5, here's my implementation:

Constructor & the method to call the service:

```
 theService;

  constructor(_service: SendFileService) {
    this.theService = _service;
  }
```

the method that will call the service:

```
imageHandler(value) {
  const service = SendFileService;
  const ImageInput = document.createElement('input');

  ImageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  ImageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
  ImageInput.classList.add('ql-image');
  ImageInput.click();

  ImageInput.addEventListener('change', function()  {
    const file = ImageInput.files[0];
    if (ImageInput.files != null && ImageInput.files[0] != null) {
    this.theService.SendFileService(file)
      .subscribe(function(res){console.log(res); });
    }
}.bind(this));
}
```

This is the service:

```
  private _url = '/api/uploadImage';

  constructor(private http: Http) {     }

       sendFileToServer(file) {

          const input = new FormData();
          input.append('file', file);
    return  this.http.post(this._url, input).map(resp => resp.json()).catch(err => Observable.throw(err));

      }
```

When i tried to run the program it gives me :

> this.theService.SendFileService is not a function

But when i tried to use the fat arrow of es6 it works perfectly:

```
imageHandler(value) {
  const service = SendFileService;
  const ImageInput = document.createElement('input');

  ImageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  ImageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
  ImageInput.classList.add('ql-image');
  ImageInput.click();

  ImageInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const file = ImageInput.files[0];
    if (ImageInput.files != null && ImageInput.files[0] != null) {
      this._service.sendFileToServer(file)
      .subscribe(resp => {this._returnedURL = resp; this.pushImageToEditor(); });
    }
});

}
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with angular, but it seems like you might be running afoul of the way arrow functions lexically handle `this`. In your arrow version this is bound to the imagehandler function, in your es5 example this refers to the scope of the anonymous function. you would need to bind the exterior `this` arg to your anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

The Code in ES6 works because

> Fat arrows change how `this` is handled.
>        Before... In ES5, `bind()` or `var that = this;` are necessary as functions create their own `this`. We need to store the parent `this`
>   in a variable that can be referenced in the callback or take care of
>   binding ourselves.

```
function CounterES5() {
  this.seconds = 0;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    this.seconds++;
  }.bind(this), 1000); // or }.bind(this), 1000) and skip that = this
}

var counterA = new CounterES5();
window.setTimeout(function() {
  ChromeSamples.log(counterA.seconds);
}, 1200);
```

> After...
>    ES6 Arrows instead bind `this` to the immediate enclosing
>    lexical scope:

```
function CounterES6() {
  this.seconds = 0;
  window.setInterval(() => this.seconds++, 1000);
}
```

[Source](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/arrows-es6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageHandler(value) {
    const service = SendFileService;
    const ImageInput = document.createElement('input');

    const theService = this.theService;

    ImageInput.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    ImageInput.setAttribute('accept', 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon');
    ImageInput.classList.add('ql-image');
    ImageInput.click();

    ImageInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
        const file = ImageInput.files[0];
        if (ImageInput.files != null && ImageInput.files[0] != null) {
            theService.SendFileService(file)
                .subscribe(function (res) { console.log(res); });
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```